# Possible with lua in redis to return all key stored in a set as a list of hashes?

Tags: performance, lua, redis

I have a structure

```
data_type:key1 - hash
data_type:key2 - hash
data_type:key3 - hash
data_type:key4 - hash
data_type:key5 - hash
data_type:index - set(key1, key2, key3, key4, key5)
```

Is it possible with lua in redis to build a script that would iterate over the set data_type:index and return all data_type:key*'s as a list of hashes?  I am still learning Lua as a I go so in my head I think it would work something like

```
collect = []
for key_name in redis.call.smemembers('data_type:index'):
    collect.append( redis.call.smembers('data_type:' + key_name)
return collect
```

Generally most of the index's have about 100 keys, each key is about 1KB, so this script would have a 100-120KB response size under ideal circumstances.

And before anyone asks, the real keys look like  'some_data:status:{64 bit hex string}'  and 'some_data:index:2013:05:09' with the {64 bit hex string} being a member of the :index set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [SSCAN command](http://redis.io/commands/sscan).

Something like the following should work in your case:

```
local collect = {}
local match_pattern = "*"
local results = redis.call("SSCAN", "data_type:index", 0, "match", match_pattern)
for i, key_name in ipairs(results[2]) do 
  -- your code here (could be different depending on your needs)
  local key_value = redis.call("GET", "data_type:" .. key_name)
  if key_value then
    table.insert(collect, key_value)
  end 
end 
return collect
```

Comment: I'll verify this soon but this looks like the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @TechyTimo see [eval](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL) and/or evalsha commands to learn how to execute it